# Extracting data from facebook URL into IFRAME using PHP

Tags: php, facebook

There is a url like this https://www.facebook.com/pages/test/?sk=app_4234&test=1

How do i get test=1 into my iframe.

Usually,you can get this by using $_REQUEST['test']; but this is n't working,how do i achieve this ?

Comment: I forgot to mention that for Canvas apps (Apps on Facebook) you can send whatever you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to get extra custom parameters but there is one that Facebook provides:

Use app_data.

> http://facebook.com/pages/PAGE_ID/?sk=app_APP_ID&app_data=YOUR_DATA

And then you get it from the getSignedRequest

```
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
$app_data = $signed_request['app_data'];
```